# How can you access the Response object inside ContainerResponseFilter?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

In Jersey 1 you can create a container response filter and get access to the Response:

```
public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response)
{
   Response r = response.getResponse();

   // Now I have access to Reponse.getMetadata(), etc.
}
```

But in Jersey 2, the ContainerResponseFilter only gives me the response context:

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext  requestContext,
                   ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
{
    // responseContext gives me the entity, but I want the JAX-RS Response object that my resources created
}
```

The implementation of ContainerResponseContext is ContainerResponse, which **requires** a JAX-RS Response object to build. So why can't I get access to it from within the filter? Am I missing something?

The problem I have is that my resources all build Response objects and attach meta data to them, and I'd like a response filter that can examine this meta data. Without access to the raw Response, this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadocs API the Response.getMetadata() is considered deprecated, even though it's not marked as such as of 2.12. The preferred alternative is to use HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

you can get access to every response object by implementing a custom ResourceMethodInvocationHandler. Look at my answer @ [Registering a custom ResourceMethodInvocationHandler in Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881675/registering-a-custom-resourcemethodinvocationhandler-in-jersey)